# Which hostname is required to send email to a user through a website created with Google Apps?

Tags: java, email, google-apps

Our website was created with Google Apps.

My website URL is `http://mydomain.com`, which is pointing to `http://sites.google.com/a/mydomain.com/`.

I want to send email to a registered user.

I am using the Apache Commons jar to send mail to the user.

I get this error message:

```
Sending the email to the following server failed : http://mail.google.com/a/mydomain.com:25
```

I used `smtpPortAddress=25` & `hostName=http://mail.google.com/a/mydomain.com`.

I am not spending money on email server setup, so I want to send email through our website.

**Which hostname is required to send mail?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if you can use port 25, for the encrypted SMTP port you can use

```
Host: smtp.gmail.com
Port: 465
Authentication: Yes
Username: you@yourdomain.com
Password: #YOUR_PASSWORD#
Security: SSL
```

Either way, just use `smtp.gmail.com` with your `@yourdomain.com` name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply !!! I used port no:465 & also tried both host name i.e smtp.gmail.com and smtp.gmail.com@mydomain.com Still got same error :( Anything wrong with me ? please do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use any mail server to sent your mail.

But if you like to use GMail the server is smtp.gmail.com.
But you also will have to make sure you authenticate as a valid gmail user.